# Can anyone help me to refactor below c# code using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I refactor below c# code

```
            foreach (var pref in ps._prefs) {
            for (int i = pref.Value.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var val = pref.Value[i];

                // validate the field presence 
                try {
                    // this evaluates the relevent field, to make sure it is still presence. 
                    var prefCode = val.PreferenceCode;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.Warn(LogType.DataLayerService,
                        $"Referred field is no longer valid for FieldChooser for preference set. {ps.GetDisplayName()}. Still proceeding to delete the Preference Set.",
                        HttpContext.Current);
                    pref.Value.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried : 
         `ps._prefs.Values.ForEach(list => list.RemoveAll(p => p?.PreferenceCode is null));`

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? `var prefCode = val.PreferenceCode;` does nothing with any effect, and catching an exception to dictate program flow isn't typically a good idea.

Comment: `ForEach` Isn't *Linq*, and unless this is a query and results in a `List` or an `IEnumerable` then i wouldn't bother. also there is no code here with also a very suspect use of `catch`

Comment: It is not good practice to use `try/catch` as an essential part of your logic. Do you have another way of determining if the `PreferenceCode` is no longer valid.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish ? With exception handling and mutation of state, the code might be clearer without LINQ.

Comment: Linq is for filtering collections. Do you want to know if `val  == null`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can work, as you want.

```
    ps._prefs.ForEach(pref => pref.Value.ForEach(val => 
         try {
                // this evaluates the relevent field, to make sure it is still presence. 
                var prefCode = val.PreferenceCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.Warn(LogType.DataLayerService,
                    $"Referred field is no longer valid for FieldChooser for preference set. {ps.GetDisplayName()}. Still proceeding to delete the Preference Set.",
                    HttpContext.Current);
                pref.Value.Remove(val);
            }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest possible I can get is

```
void Main()
{
    List<Test> prefs = new List<Test>(){ new Test (), new Test(){PreferenceCode = 1 }};

    var res = prefs.Select(x => {
        if (x?.PreferenceCode == null)
            Debug.Write(x);
        return x;
    }).Where(x => x?.PreferenceCode != null);

    res.Dump();
}

public class Test {
  public inb? PreferenceCode {get; set;}
}
```

With RemoveAll

```
var res2 = prefs.RemoveAll(x => {
   if (x?.PreferenceCode == null){
     Debug.Write(x);
     return true;
   }

   return false;
});

res2.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. Not very sure whether it works correctly!!

```
foreach(var item in ps._prefs.Values)
   item.RemoveAll(i => i.Preference Code is null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this LINQ:

```
ps._prefs.ForEach(perf => perf.Value = perf.Value.Where(v => v.PreferenceCode != null).ToList()))
```

Here I am assigning the `Value` field of `perf` with a filtered list where `preferenceCode` is not null.